# How to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    long n=600851475143;
    int i,j,flag;
    for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        flag=1;
        if(n%i==0)//finds factors backwards
        {
            for(j=2;j<=(n/i)/2;j++)//checks if factor is prime
            {
                if((n/i)%j==0)
                    flag=0;
            }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                printf("%d\n",n/i);//displays largest prime factor and exits
                exit(0);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

The code above works for `n = 6008514751`. However, it doesn't work for `n = 600851475143`, even though that number still is within the range of a `long`.
What can I do to make it work?

Comment: longs size is depending on your enviroment, there are systems where long can hold only 4 byte so "600851475143" would be too large

Comment: In what way does the code not work?

Comment: Your machine is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does your computer explode? Does it just print nothing?

Comment: the code keeps compiling forever.mostly,looping endlessly

Comment: It really keeps *compiling*, or do you mean it keeps *running*? Those are two very different things, and you should understand the difference. And are you sure it loops *endlessly*, or does it just take a long time? Note that the two inputs you're comparing differ by two orders of magnitude. They start with the same digits, but they're not actually close to each other, so comparing them might not be wise.

Comment: I get errors and warnings: 'warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type; In function 'int main()': 3:13: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion; 18:23: error: 'exit' was not declared in this scope'. Do not *ever* ask "what's wrong with this code" without mentioning any compiler errors.

Comment: keeps running,i mean. and im saying it may be an endless loop. but it works for 2 digits less. so it exceeds the range of long. so what datatype do i use instead?

Comment: While you were contemplating how to solve the reported errors (?), I ran your program using `long long` (which, I should mention, gave me a "warning: ISO C++ 1998 does not support 'long long"). After a while it said `6857`. Is that an expected result?

Comment: yes,thats the answer.thanks.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, that's expected on a C++98 compiler.  You need C++11 for "long long" to be a standard feature.  The fact that you got a warning instead of an error says that you do have at least some C++11 support, though.  Check your build settings (on GNU g++ ports, the compiler flag is -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x (or -std=gnu++11 to enable GNU extensions to C++).

Comment: why everyone is talking about c++? he tagged the question as c and thats quiet diferent to c++. Especially if you go that deep in detail.

Comment: @Zaibis: fair point. Can't check myself atm, so can you check what changes are needed to run on C?

Comment: @Jongware the point is, I dont know how the c++ standard is handling about size of integer types but in C the standard just says which type has to support which size at minimum. and everything else is absolute implementation defined and cant be specified by hardware, arch, OS or anything else. It's just specified in the `limits.h` and each implementation can hold it as it want. Thats what you also can see in my disscusion on haccks answr http://stackoverflow.com/a/19360489/2003898. Or the one in my answr http://stackoverflow.com/a/19360374/2003898 with the corresponding ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 quote.

Answer (score 5):

One potential problem is that `i` and `j` are `int`, and could overflow for large `n` (assuming `int` is narrower than `long`, which it often is).

Another issue is that for n=600,851,475,143 your program does quite a lot of work (the largest factor is 6857). It is not unreasonable to expect it to take a long time to complete.

Comment: well,it never stops running

Comment: @user2878665: What makes you sure it's "never" rather than "not for a long time"?

Comment: @user2878665: that's hardly surprising; your code is so inefficient, by, I estimate, about 2 orders of magnitude. See my answer. (+1 to NPE for the clarity of answer - and providing ad space for mine)

Comment: @NPE:it does execute. but takes a crazy long time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `long`s in place of `int`s. Better still, use `uint64_t` which has been defined since C99 (acknowledge Zaibis). It is a 64 bit unsigned integral type on all platforms. (The code as you have it will overflow on some platforms).

**And now we need to get your algorithm working more quickly:**

Your test for prime is inefficient; you don't need to iterate over all the even numbers. Just iterate over primes; up to and equal to the square root of the number you're testing (not half way which you currently do).

Where do you get the primes from? Well, call your function recursively. Although in reality I'd be tempted to cache the primes up to, say, 65536.

Comment: this question is by the way not for c++, it is c tagged. But int64_t is also implemented since C99. But would be nice if ou could correct that ;)

Comment: Since c99 the standard headers still include stdint.h. Not since c11 but if he is compiling c11 that would be correct anyway. So nvm.

Comment: @Zaibis; I've checked and, needless to say, your're correct: uint64_t has been around since C99. Answer re-amended.

Answer (score 1):

From ISO/IEC 9899:TC3

> 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types

[...]

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude(absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.

[...]

> — minimum value for an object of type long int
>
> LONG_MIN -2147483647 // -(2^31 - 1)
>
> — maximum value for an object of type long int
>
> LONG_MAX +2147483647 // 2^31 - 1

EDIT:

Sorry I forgot to add what this should tell you.

The point is long doesn't even need to be able to hold the value you mentioned, as the standard says it has to be able to hold at least 4 Bytes with sign so it could be possible that your machine is just able to hold values up to 2147483647 in a variable of type `long`.

Answer (score 1):

On 32-bit machine `long` range from `-2,147,483,648`  to `2,147,483,647` and On 64-bit machine its range is from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (**NOTE**: This is not mandated by C standard and may vary from one compiler to another).
As OP said in comment he is on 32-bit, `600851475143` goes out of range as it is not fit in the range of `long`.

Comment: It is not true that it is depending on the arch. It would be even legal to have on a 64bit arch where is long just keeping 32bit. View my answer what the standard says about this.

Comment: @zaibis; Yes it depends on arch.

Comment: Aren't you listening? it DOESN'T. I quoted the standard just a few lines down. the standard says long has to hold at least 4Bytes. so it has nothing to do with arch!

Comment: Who said there was overflow? If the code works for 6 billion, it should work for 600 billion, too; neither fits in a 32-bit int.

Comment: @Zaibis; I persist on what I said.

Comment: @haccks Please edit it, that long ranges is depending on the architecture. The standard would even allow a 64bit system to have `long`s range from -2.147.483.648 to 2.147.483.647. and on 32 Bit from -9.223.372.036.854.775.808 to 9.223.372.036.854.775.807 . So its complete WRONG to say "Your `long`s range is from ... to ... because you are on xBit system. The standard just sets a minimum range for each type, everything else is implementation defined. So if you dont cahnge it I'm gonna downvote.

Comment: @Zaibis; I am removing that line just because standard says nothing about it.

Comment: @haccks The standard SAYS something about it look here: "Annex E
(informative)
Implementation limits
1 The contents of the header <limits.h> are given below, in alphabetical order. The
**minimum magnitudes** shown shall be replaced by **implementation-defined magnitudes**
with the same sign." And at least, any way: as long the standard doesn't say it is arch dependend. you cant suggest it does. it will never be arch dependend as the standard doesnt say explicit that it is. But nevermind now, as you corrected it I'm fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `n` to `long long int` .. and change i,j to long

EDIT: define n like this :

```
long long int n = 600851475143LL;
```

`LL` - is a suffix to enforce long long type ...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
int prime_numbers(int value);

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long int num = 600851475143;
  int flag, x, largest_num = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    // Find the factors of num
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
      x = prime_numbers(i);
      if (x != 0)
      {
      // Find the largest prime number
      if (largest_num == 0 || largest_num < x)
        largest_num = x;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Largest prime factor: %d\n", largest_num);
  return 0;
}

int prime_numbers(int value) {

  int n, i, flag = 0;
  n = value;
  // 0 and 1 are not prime numbers
  // change flag to 1 for non-prime number
  if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    flag = 1;

  for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {
    // if n is divisible by i, then n is not prime
    // change flag to 1 for non-prime number
    if (n % i == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  // flag is 0 for prime numbers
  if (flag == 0)
    return n;

  return 0;
}
```