# How to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143 in C?

Tags: c, project

I try to find the largest prime factor of `600851475143` with the code as given below.
However, this code does not return any output, not even errors or warnings.

Where do I go wrong?

Code:

```js
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j, k, mpf;

  for (i = 1; i < 600851475143; i++)
  {
    if (600851475143 % i == 0)
    {
      k = 0;
      for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        if (i % j == 0)
          k++;

      if (k == 2)
        mpf = i;
    }
  }

  printf("\nThe largest prime factor of 600851475143 is: %ld\n", mpf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360281/code-for-finding-largest-prime-factor-why-doesnt-this-work-for-600851475143 or try search `[c] 600851475143` in this site.

Comment: Your program won't even print *anything* until it has finished - almost forever. And since you didn't initialise `mpf` it could print junk.

Comment: Rather that complaining about being required to write some text, why not put some effort into writing a good question? For example, tell us what is "Project euler prob 3"?

Comment: I get: `example.c:25:5: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`. When I run, after a while I get `Floating point exception (core dumped)`.

Comment: @Fred Larson As a 32-bit `i` is always smaller than `600851475143`, `i` increments past `INT_MAX` certainly it eventually becomes `0`.  `600851475143%0` caused the "Floating point exception", even though it is an integer math.

Comment: trying looping upto sqrt of 600851475143 and use long long datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Looping up to 600 billion will take forever — not just a long time, but *impossible* because it exceeds what can be stored in an `int` (usually up to 2^31-1 these days, but could be as small as 2^15-1 according to the C standard).

What you need is a smarter algorithm.  Rather than giving you the solution verbatim, I suggest that you look at [existing answers](//codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=project+euler+3) and work out a solution in C by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping from 1 to 600851475143, you should loop from 2 to the square root of 600851475143:

```
long long num=600851475143;
long i=2;   
while(i<=sqrt(num))
{   
    //printf("%lu\n",num);
    if(num%i==0)
    {
        while(num%i==0)
        {
            num/=i;
        }           
        if(num==1)
        {
            num=i;
            break;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
}
printf("%lu",num);
```