# The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

Tags: java

My program is not working on eclipse.. And i dont know whats wrong with it..
Plz help..
And plz tell the reason as well.

```
 public class ProblemThree {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            long a=0L, z=0L;
            long n=600851475143L;

            for(long i=2;i<=n ;++i)
            {
                if(600851475143L % i==0)
                {
                    a=i;

                    if(a%2==0)
                        {;  }
                    else if(a%3==0)
                        { ;}
                    else if(a%5==0)
                        { ;}
                    else if(a%7==0)
                        { ;}
                    else if (a>z)
                    { 
                        z=a;
                    }

                }

            }

            System.out.println(z);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "not working".

Comment: no response on console

Comment: Have you tried it on smaller numbers? I've seen programs like this take a *really* long time; it doesn't mean it's not working.

Comment: The number is very large.Try to optimize the loop.check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515940/project-euler-prob-3-in-c/30516230#30516230

Comment: Just a hint: you can increase the divisor by two always to only handle odd numbers since no other even number is prime than 2

Comment: Actually, you can do more than that - only check 2 and 3, and then numbers that are of the form `6n+1` or `6n-1`. And you only have to go up to `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: 600 billion iterations could take a while. You could optimize your loop by only going up to sqrt(n) and starting your loop counter at 3 and incrementing by 2 each iteration, since an even number can't be prime.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the input, the actual output, and the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for your feedback but i have solved this question myself with the following code.. :)

public class ProblemThree {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    long n=600851475143L;

    for(long i=2;i<n ;++i)
    {
        while(n % i==0)
        {//for yes
            n=n/i;

        }   

    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your program isn't "returning" anything because it is still running.  Your loop is still iterated.  Your code needs to be modified to be more performant. Here is my solution to the same problem.

```
long testNum = 600851475143l; 
int largestFactor = 0; 
long loopMax = 17425170l; //largest known prime  
for (int i = 3; i * i <= loopMax; i++) { 
    boolean isPrime = true;             
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
       if (i % j == 0) { 
          isPrime = false; 
          break; 
       } 
    }                         
    if (isPrime && testNum % i == 0) { 
        System.out.println("prime factor: " + i); 
        largestFactor = i; 
        loopMax = (testNum / i) + 1; 
    } 
} 
System.out.println("result is: " + largestFactor);
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! Could you please explain the algorithm or at least point me at some reading material? I have never seen this solution before..

Comment: @Bobby you can optimize your solution by looping upto only sqrt of 6008514751431 which is 775146.

Comment: This is actually a pretty brute force solution and  [Wikipedia told me the largest prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number)

Answer (score 0):

```
package Euler;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class euler3 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long num;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        num= sc.nextLong();

        for(int i=2;i<num; i++)
        {
            while(num%i == 0)
            {
                //System.out.println(i);
                num=num/i;
            }
        }
        if(num>2)
            System.out.println(num);

    }

}
```

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
The largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 is 6857.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also attempted the problem and solved with this

```
public class LargestPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long x = 600851475143L;

        int LargestPrimeFactor = 2;

        while (x % 2 == 0) {
// clears through factors of 2 in the number
            x /= 2;

        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= x; i += 2) {
            while (x % i == 0) {
                x /= i;
                LargestPrimeFactor = i;
                break;
            }

        }
        
          System.out.println(LargestPrimeFactor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int SieveOfEratosthenes(int x,long long signed int n)
{
    bool prime[x];                                 //use sieve upto square root of 
                                                       // required number
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
 
    for (long long signed int p = 2; p * p <= x; p++)    
    {
        if (prime[p] == true) 
        {
            for (long long signed int i = p * p; i <= x; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }
    }
    int res;
    for (long long signed int p = 2; p <= x; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            {
                if(n%p==0)   //if number is divisble by prime number than update with 
                res=p;        //latest value of prime number
            }
            return res;
}
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout<<SieveOfEratosthenes(775146,600851475143);//Return the answer

    // long long signed int n;cin>>n;   for value of n
   //cout<<SieveOfEratosthenes(sqrt(n),n);
    return 0;
}
```